# Webdriver Internet Explorer .Click() timeout

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

For the last couple of days I've been struggling with IEDriverServer.exe and any version of IE.  I have narrowed it down to any `.Click()` commands that I make.  When I use one, the test just seems to hang until it errors with a message like this:

```
"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:2833/session/0cc60081-2142-427a-91b2-4563da3c3725/element/2c8403f6-7b06-4397-b2be-997a63ac3de1/click timed out after 60 seconds."
```

Also during this, the element I have tried to click completely hogs all the focus making clicking on anything else (even manually) difficult.  If I manually hover over another element, it will flicker between the hovered element and the clicked element. I then enabled some logging and after a click event, all I see are the following:

```
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:407 Browser.cpp(419) Entering Browser::Wait
D 2015-02-26 13:29:25:407 Browser.cpp(423) Navigate Events Completed.
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:407 Browser.cpp(648) Entering Browser::GetActiveDialogWindowHandle
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:407 Browser.cpp(192) Entering Browser::GetWindowHandle
D 2015-02-26 13:29:25:408 Browser.cpp(439) Browser busy property is true.
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:408 IECommandExecutor.cpp(387) Entering IECommandExecutor::WaitThreadProc
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:608 IECommandExecutor.cpp(207) Entering IECommandExecutor::OnWait
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:608 IECommandExecutor.cpp(580) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetCurrentBrowser
T 2015-02-26 13:29:25:608 IECommandExecutor.cpp(586) Entering IECommandExecutor::GetManagedBrowser
```

repeated over the over again.

After some reading, I have tried a few things.  Instead of using `.Click()`, I changed it to use `.SendKeys("\n")`.  This helps pass the test, but seems like a very hacked solution and doesn't simulate an end user as fully as I would like.
I then started the browser with the option of `EnableNativeEvents = false`.  This stopped the focus hogging issue, but the `.Click()` will still not actually work and neither will the `.SendKeys("\n")`, both resulting in the same logs as before.
Clutching at straws, I also tried ignoring the zoom level with `IgnoreZoomLevel = true` to no effect.

Is my only option to use the `.SendKeys("\n")`?

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with very much the same problem and ended up with a hack that tries to click normally first and then uses `.SendKeys("\n")` as a fallback. It looks like this (slightly simplified):

```
public static void ClickWithIeHackFailover(this IWebElement element)
{
    try
    {
        element.Click();
    }
    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
        if (e.Message != "Timed out waiting for page to load.")
        {
            element.SendKeys("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

It allows me to try the standard clicking first and then use `SendKeys("\n")` as a fail over.

In order to get it working in all cases I needed to set the page load timeout like this when creating the driver:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

This solves states where the browser won't return execution to Selenium because the page is busy which might be your case since you've got `Browser busy property is true.` in your log.

I had this so question open while I came up with the hack: [Why can't Selenium WebDriver find my element in a catch clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798527/why-cant-selenium-webdriver-find-my-element-in-a-catch-clause/29896392#29896392). It might give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old post, but thought of sharing the way I handled this issue.  I ran into the exact same issue with every click().  I used the Javascript executory class and used the same object to click the element that is desired.  And this worked like charm in my case.  I came up with the following function:

```
protected void myClick (WebElement elementToClick)    
{     
    String browser = ConfigManager.getWebBrowserName();
    if ((browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) | browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internet explorer")) {
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",elementToClick);    
    }
    else {
        elementToClick.click();
    }               
}
```